# Using eclipse to compile c++

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ but have some programming experience with R and Matlab. My OS is Win 7.

I downloaded " Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers " from Eclipse website and tried to run a simple program, but the compiler doesn't even know "cout＂, the simplest c++ command.

I do see some answers on the website, but it is still a little hard for me to follow.

[Eclipse CDT: Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803685/eclipse-cdt-symbol-cout-could-not-be-resolved)

First of all, should I install ＂Eclipse Standard 4.3" （ the so called platform?) or " Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers " ? Most of the documents I found on the web use the platform rather than C++ IDE.

Could someone recommend a step to step guide (guide for "idiot" like me ) for programming c++ with eclipse?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you try "std::cout" or otherwise specify the namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the C++ specific version or the standard version should work. What I believe is happening with you is that you don't have a C++ compiler installed. gcc is the most popular one, just Google it. Do note that Eclipse is **not** a compiler and it does not include a compiler, either.

As for a guide, a quick google search found the [Eclipse C++ documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcdt_o_home.htm). As you are new to StackOverflow, please be sure to read the guidelines, and go over the [about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page to get acquainted with how the site works.

Also see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368976/getting-c-to-compile-inside-eclipse). Let me know if you have any questions, and welcome to the community!

My suggestion on the matter, if you are new to IDEs, you may want to start with [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop#product-express-desktop). It is very easy to use, and the express edition is free. I believe it includes a C++ compiler as well.